# C# join two datatables with conditions

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatables, both have a `callID` column.

I want to join them with condition that the `value` column is equal to `I`

I tried this:

```
var result = from row1 in table.AsEnumerable()
             join row2 in tabelPopup.AsEnumerable()
                on row1.Field<string> ("callID") equals row2.Field<string> ("callID")
             where row1.Field<string>("value") equals "I";
```

but I got a syntax error

> Can't convert string to bool

on the last line of code

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part should be:

```
where row1.Field<string>("value") == "I"
select something;
```

Comment: I want to select everything, so what did you mean by `select something` ?

Comment: You have to specify which fields you want to select `new { row1.Field<string> ("callID"), ... }`. Or if you just want the two rows you can write `new { row1, row2 }`

Comment: when I did this `select new { row1.Field<string>("Agent")};` I got `Invalid anonymous type member declarator`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Write it as: `select new { Agent = row1.Field<string>("Agent")};`